# Cumulative distribution function subrange

Tags: statistics, inequality, probability-distributions

I'm working on a problem from "Applied statistics  and probability for engineers" by Montgomery. 
The problem is, given:

$
F(x)=
\begin{cases}
0,\quad &x<1\\
0.5, &1<=x<3\\
1, &3<=x\\
\end{cases}
$

A cumulative distribution function. Find

(a)$P(X<=3)$

(b)$P(X<=2)$

(c)$P(1<=X<=2)$

(d)$P(X>2)$

I worked like this:

(a)$P(X<=3) = F(3) = 1$

(b)$P(X<=2) = F(2) = 0.5$

(c)$P(1<=X<=2) = F(2)-F(1) = 0$

(d)$P(X>2) = 1-F(2)=0.5$

The book give the answers: 1, 0.5 , 0.5, 0.5. So my third answer is incorrect. Can someone comment on my procedure here, I have doubts about how to treat the limit values, for example, what's the difference between these:

$P(1<=X<=3)$

$P(1<X<=3)$

$P(1<=X<3)$

$P(1<X<3)$

The book doesn't go deep about this topic.

Thanks to all of you.

Answer (score 0):

I would think the result was derived as follows, remeber that when conditions $A$ and $B$ are independant then

$$P(A\cap B) = P(A)\cdot P(B)$$

Now look at $P(1\leqslant X \leqslant 3)$ as follows:

$$\begin{align}
P(1\leqslant X \leqslant 3) & = P(1\leqslant X \text{ and } X\leqslant 3) \\
& = P(1\leqslant X) \cdot P(X\leqslant 3) \\
& = P(X\geqslant 1)\cdot F(3)\\
& = [1-P(X< 1)] \cdot F(3)\\
& = [1-0]\cdot 0.5\\
& = 0.5
\end{align}$$

In the same way you could calculate the other probability's.
For example:
$$\begin{align}
P(1< X \leqslant 3) & = P(1< X \text{ and } X\leqslant 3) \\
& = P(1< X) \cdot P(X\leqslant 3) \\
& = P(X> 1)\cdot F(3)\\
& = [1-P(X\leqslant 1)] \cdot F(3)\\
& = [1-0.5]\cdot 0.5\\
& = 0.25
\end{align}$$

This seems fair, since the chance that $X \in {]1,3]}$ should be less or equal then $X\in [1,3]$, since ${]1,3]}\subseteq [1,3]$ (or informal 'as the second interval contains *more* numbers').

Comment: Thanks, I stil have some doubts, but I think I can manage drawing the f(x) (density plot) and reasoning about the intervals provided.

Comment: @FranciscoAngel: The probability density plot seems far from trivial in this case, what do you have?

Comment: I sketched it in this link https://goo.gl/2iQjHP , I expect a simple pdf because this is a minor topic in the book (just a pair of pages) so I assume the exercises to be of the introductory class.